# Beginner: AVR C++ Atmel Studio 6

Tags: microcontroller, atmel, atmega

I'm having an issue working out what libraries I have access to.  I understand that I can use the Atmel Studio 6 IDE to program the microcontroler (Atmega328p) in C++; however, I can't work out where it is documented what libraries I have access to.  For example, can I use the STL (so like, vectors, deques...)?  If someone could point me towards some documentation, that'd be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atmel Studio 6 doesn't come with an implementation of STL. There are some libraries that avr-gcc comes with--look in:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Atmel Toolchain\AVR8 GCC\Native\3.4.2.1002\avr8-gnu-toolchain\avr\include\`

That does not contain `<vector>` or `<deques>`, but it does have `<string>`. There *are* lots of STL implementations ported over to Atmel Studio though: take a look at:

http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11119

http://andybrown.me.uk/wk/2011/01/15/the-standard-template-library-stl-for-avr-with-c-streams/